# Azure Resource VM WinRM image

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, vpn

I'm able to setup WinRM on  a VM using the following [winrm](http://blog.ricardovillalobos.com/?p=1871) . Would like to create an image of this VM and use it to create other VMs. The VM configured has been sysprep and an new VM created however WInRM is not working.

Is this possible or would I have to do the steps every time I create a VM from my image. These vms would be created on the same vpn

UPDATE :
WinRM appears to be running but can not connect. All VMs will be created in the same VPN.

Would it be something to do with the certificate created. When creating a VM from the image the machine name will be different.

Comment: WinRM is not running or can't connect to it? Does your VMs create with NSG? VMs would be created on the same VPN, P2S VPN?

Comment: Use WinRM to connect Azure VM via VPN?

Comment: @JasonYe-Msft using winrm in the same VPN. I have two servers on the same vpn.

Comment: P2S VPN or S2S vpn?

Comment: Sorry I'm still quite new to this. How do I determine this? I did no extra configuration of VPN.

Comment: can you manual connect to your VPN in new VM?

Comment: I can RDP to the machine?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150904/discussion-between-jason-ye-msft-and-boomerang).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, after configure WinRM completed, then sysprep this VM, and use this VHD to create new VM, the WinRM will work as original VM.

We should **add trust host** on your local PC with this script:

`Set-Item wsman:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -value *`

Then we can use this script to winrm Azure VM:

```
$username = 'username'
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -string 'password' -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $pass
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName "FQDN" -Credential $cred -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck)
```

By the way, if we want to winrm this VM via public IP address, we should add port 5985 to NSG inbound rules.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, in my lab, it seems we can't use certificate with different computer.